# Set user facebook user cover image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have searched the Facebook API for anything to use to change the users profile and cover image.

i want the user to be able to set their profile and cover from a list of images i have in my mobile app.

Any ideas on this?

Thanx.

Comment: Not possible for user accounts via API (only for pages).

Comment: Ok i was afraid of that....  thanx.